# Store an array of string into a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Why instead of helping you put a negative vote each time.
At least say what's wrong.

I tried some advice found here as `JSON.stringify()` but when I retrieve the data attribute I get only the first word "2003/09/01".

Thank you.

I have a loop who put the string into an array.

```
var row = date + " - " + res + " - " + v.CSERV + " / " + v.CHAMB + " / " + v.LIT + " (" + v.TYPMVT + ")";
dataDetail.push(row);
```

The output of the array

> ["2003/09/01 - 07:45 - 02 / 07 / 01 (Admission)", "2003/09/03 - 15:00
>   - 01 / 46 / 01 (Transfert)", "2003/09/05 - 10:00 - 01 / 45 / 01 (Transfert)", "2003/09/08 - 09:14 - 01 / 45 / 01 (Transfert)",
>   "2003/09/09 - 11:00 - 01 / 45 / 01 (Sortie)"]

Data attibute is as follows:

```
$('#Historique .items').append(`
                            <div class='item'>
                                <div class='content detail' data-detail=` + JSON.stringify(dataDetail) + `>                                       
                                    <p>` + "du " + dateD + " (" + value.UNI + ") au " + dateS + " (" + value.UNI + ") Nr° Séjour : " + value.NUM + " (" + value.TYP + ")" + `</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>`);
```

Comment: How do you call this line of code? `data-detail=\` + JSON.stringify(dataDetail) + \``? Why backticks?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: You need `\`somehtml = 'data-detail="${JSON.stringify(dataDetail)}" ....'\``  - because you need to quote the string

Comment: @mplungjan The line of code the OP provided implies that the string is much longer and that `date-detail` is part of the string, not `+ JSON.stringify(dataDetail) +`. `date-detail = something` is invalid JavaScript.

Comment: We need to see the code of how you’re _retrieving_ the `date` attribute. I don’t see how you could get only the first “word”, since the output of the array (`dataDetail`, right?) would be valid JSON, when passed to `JSON.stringify`, and calling `JSON.parse` on it again should work as you need it.

Comment: @Xufox see my update

Comment: @mplungjan There might be more things to escape. JSON is not safe to inject in html strings. :)

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko  I edited the topic

Comment: Actually, instead of constructing an HTML string like that, it’d be better to add the `data` attribute later. Assuming `detail` is the `<div class="content detail">` element, assign `detail.dataset.detail = JSON.stringify(`…`);`. This would take care of escaping characters like `"` which may mess with your HTML attributes.

Comment: @Xufox I retrieve like that $(this).data('detail') because JSON.parse($(this).data('detail')) gives me an error

Comment: I have not only one div with detail class that why I do like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not safe to use JSON in html attributes. It definitely contains qoutes. Also it might contain `<>` that would entirely ruin your markup.

Instead you could use `jquery.data` as an external data storage.

```
const item = $(... mark element with data-detail...) // create jquery object
item.find('[data-detail]').data('detail', data) // find marked element and put data to its expando object (avoiding html to dom phase)
```

Working demo below

```js
$(function() {
  const data = ["2003/09/01 - 07:45 - 02 / 07 / 01 (Admission)", "2003/09/03 - 15:00 - 01 / 46 / 01 (Transfert)", "2003/09/05 - 10:00 - 01 / 45 / 01 (Transfert)", "2003/09/08 - 09:14 - 01 / 45 / 01 (Transfert)", "2003/09/09 - 11:00 - 01 / 45 / 01 (Sortie)"]

  const target = $('#target');
  
  target.on('click', '.detail', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('detail'))
  })
  
  const item = $(`<div class='item'>
                                <div class='content detail' data-detail>                                 
                                    <p>Whatever you do here. Click here to get data-detail</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>`)
  item.find('[data-detail]').data('detail', data)                           
                            

  target.append(item)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Yury

Comment: @Mercenaire Glad I could help.

Comment: When I inspect the element I saw that the data attribute doesn't contain data. Does the DOM hid it?

Comment: DOM doesn't contain the data. Jquery uses external expando object to store data associated with the element.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: This is why it allows to store complex even non-serializable objects (say functions or circular data structures)

Comment: Do you have a link or a book who explain this.

Comment: @Mercenaire [Docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data/Data.js) is pretty much straightforward.